# How to make an interactive activity which can be updated regularly?

Tags: android

I want to make a UI which can be updated regularly without updating the app itself (I want to make an event announcer meaning that every event the admin make the activity should be updated with the latest event)

Well I have an idea how to do this by making a page on my website and view it using a webview. So my question is? Is there a better way to do that other than this? Will suggest how or just link me to website or even give me a keyword to search it.

Everything is appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details. Which part of the UI should it be possible to update. If possible, provide sample image showing the result you would like to achieve.

Comment: On top of my mind, you could have periodic/async task which pools content from some website, configurable xml or database or whatever. And when you have new content, display it.

Comment: Well like shazam or any news app if it possible i can post an image of the apps but i think it violate stack over flow regulations  (my first time on the site) :3. And i will for research periodic/async task thank you a lot.

Comment: I would go with periodic pooling of dynamic web content, or static configurable resources as suggested in the comment above. Either that, or to push notifications to your own application which would silently trigger update by pooling.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is ambiguous! But look for Handlers.
Define a fixed interval where you can refresh the UI by giving the delayed messages!